# how can I solve this sum?

Tags: summation, assumptions

how can I solve this sum?

```
Sum[1/(x[p]-x[q]),{p,1,l},p\[NotEqual]q]
```

I tried these codes but not workin'

```
Sum[1/(x[p]-x[q]),{p,1,l},Assumption->p\[NotEqual]q]]
```

and also this

```
Assuming[p\[NotEqual]q,Sum[1/(x[p]-x[q]),{p,1,k}]]
```

Comment: Did you see: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html

Comment: `Sum[If[p != q, 1/(x[p] - x[q]), 0], {p, 1, l}]`